# How to get the second to last downloaded file?

Tags: python, file

I already know how to get the latest file in a folder:

```
import glob
import os

list_of_files = glob.glob('/path/to/folder/*') # * means all if need specific format then *.csv
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print(latest_file)
```

How can I get the next to last file in a folder?

Answer (score 1):

Sort the files according to their `ctime` and take the second-to-last:

```py
import glob
import os

list_of_files = glob.glob('/path/to/folder/*')
files_by_time = sorted(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print(files_by_time[-2])
```